# Cannot center (vertically) linked image and text

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image and text that I want to center vertically using this method:

```
position:relative;
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
```

It works great on in most cases on both images and text.

However, I want to make both the text and images links (using `<a href="">`) AND I want to resize the image from large to small so as to look good on Retina (e.g. MacBook) screens.

Here is an example of what I have written so far, with dummy content and logo:

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-image">
        <a href="#"><img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/240px-Smiley.svg.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-text">
        <a href="#">Logo text here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.logo {
    height:64px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue
}

.logo-image {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:32px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    display:inline-block
}

.logo-text {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    display:inline-block
}
```

This code is basically what I have so far (with the real logo and text substituted).

You can find a live version on jsfiddle.net here: http://jsfiddle.net/kLq28h17/

I would really appreciate the help if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong - why does the image not resize and center properly as I would like it to?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT 1: Managed to get the logo resized correctly thanks to Stephan Muller. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/0f5rncqd - Now I just need to get the text centered correctly.

EDIT 2 - FIXED! : Stephan Muller managed to fix the problem. See his comments and here: http://jsfiddle.net/0f5rncqd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're styling the div that contains the image, but you're not styling the image itself in any way. The image has no way to know how to adapt to its surroundings, so it doesn't.

This rule should always resize the image to have a maximum height of whatever container around it that has a set size:

```
.logo-image img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLq28h17/1/

**-edit-**
That only fixed the image sizing. The vertical centering is a separate problem. The easiest way to fix this is not by having each in their own box and vertically centering those, but by vertically centering the logo contents as a whole and then relying on the intrinsic `vertical-align`-property that images already have.

By putting the image and link in a box with your `translateY` trick I got the contents as a whole vertically centered. To align the image and text both in the center of that box I just set `vertical-align: middle` to the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/0f5rncqd/1/

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot with resizing the image correctly. Now, however, the text does not center correctly. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/0f5rncqd/

Comment: Oops, overlooked that. Updated my answer.